# How to change a default looking forget password template in django

Tags: python, html, django

[image: hi! wanna make a look like the below pic! but soon after i press reset password button, at the top right corner the next page appears as Django administration, which i dont want to see!]

plz note the below codings!

```
urls.py

url(r'^reset-password/', auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(template_name='frgt_pswd.html'), name='reset_password'),
    url(r'^reset-password/done/', auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(template_name='pswrd_sent.html'), name='reset_password_done'),
    url(r'^reset-password/confirm/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z]+)-(?P<token>,+)/', auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(template_name='enter_new_pswd.html'), name='password_reset_confirm'),
    url(r'^reset-password/complete/$', auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(template_name='pswd_reset_cmplte.html'), name='password_reset_complete'),
```

As you can see the above code, i have added the templates which i wanted too! But only first page is appearing.

[image: tis is the page appearing after i press reset password! which i wanted to change! Please help!]

HTML code

```
<fieldset class="module aligned">
    <div class="form-row field-email">

        <label for="id_email">Email address:</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" maxlength="300" required id="id_email" />
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Reset my password" />
</fieldset>
```

Please help!

Comment: plz note that! i want to change all the forget password page according to the 1st pic! but as i click reset my password! next page which contains "Django Administration" appears, which i wanna chnage! Help me!

Comment: Don't use comments for things that should be in the body of the question. "Edit" the question and put these details there.

Comment: Please show the complete `urls.py` and the project's `urls.py` (where you include your app's urls) as well.